# Vim no end of line on last line or eof

Tags: vim, end-of-line, eof

I am trying to setup vim to skip adding eol on last line or eof, i have tried this

```
:set binary
:set noeol
:w
```

which is not perfect cause binary override filetype for later use.

Any other option to set this, i don't need newline on last line.

Comment: The binary option doesn't do anything to filetype.

Comment: To whom it may concern: Why did you vote to close this? The FAQ tells that *“software tools commonly used by programmers”* are on-topic.

Comment: @hobbs setting file to binary disable many options, :help bin

Comment: and none of them are filetype, :help bin

Comment: Similar: [VIM Disable Automatic Newline At End Of File](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1050640/55075) at SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is even better i found somewhere:

```
au BufWritePre * :set binary | set noeol
au BufWritePost * :set nobinary | set eol
```

Comment: Also it will be useful for some cases to prepend `set noeol` in your .vimrc by default.

Answer (score 18):

I wanted to add an answer that I think can be as useful.  The selected answer **always** remove the EOL on files even if they had one to begin with.  This may be the behavior that you want, it also may not be.  In my opinion I want to **preserve** the EOL as I originally opened the file.

What I suggest is a slight modification.  Put `set binary` at the top of your `.vimrc` file.  This way any files will open in binary mode.  If they have no EOL then vim will detect this and leave it NOEOL.  If they have an EOL then it'll recognize it as having an EOL and leave it be.

If you would like *new* files to also not have EOL then you should set,

```
au BufNewFile * set noeol
```

The commands for the chap would be if you *always* want NOEOL **ever**.  The one thing to be aware of is that if you have a file with spaces at the bottom, then you will lose spaces at the end.  This is because the following happens,

1. VIM reads the file and see a newline at the end and thinks, OK, this is a file with a newline (regardless of whether in binary mode or not).
2. When you then write a file it executes the autocmd,

   1. set binary mode
   2. set noeol (this deletes the EOL that VIM *thought* was ending the file and deletes it.
   3. the file gets saved
3. Now you have a file that has one less EOL in it.

This process will repeat until the EOL's are gone and the file ends in a single character.  With my setup, what happens is the file is opened and if VIM sees at *least* one EOL then it keeps it internally.  If you save that file, no matter what it is there (you can check by typing `set eol?`.  In the case that you want to get rid of that internally stored EOL you just say `set noeol` and then save and **BOOM**, the last EOL is removed.

WHOOO, I am winded typing this.

Answer (score 5):

From vim documentation:

```
'binary' 'bin'      boolean (default off)
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
    This option should be set **before** editing a binary file.  You can also
```

You should therefore use `vim -b` or `:e ++bin file`, or reload using `:e! ++bin`.

Comment: Binary doesn't work for me, cause it reset filetype, any other option to disable eol on eof?

Comment: Then use `:setf your_file_type` to enable it back?

Comment: I need this for php files, and its to much hacking, enabling binary, setting noel, saving file, and than disabling binary and setting file type. I also use NERDTree which i would probably have to hack to get this functionality.

Comment: This is the best answer by far! In 1 sentence you give 3 powerful solutions to the OP's issue. I was able to combine `vim -b myfile` and `:set noeol` to meet my needs and now I have a skill that I can take anywhere. I don't have to have my .vimrc file to be powerful. I know how to use the power of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with this:

```
" php remove eol from end of file
autocmd FileType php setlocal noeol binary fileformats="mac,unix,dos"
```

Thank you all.

Cheers.