# Python preppy producing offensive leading blank line

Tags: python, templating, smtplib

I'm trying to use preppy to template some email messages, but it inserts a leading blank line which causes SMTP to treat everything as message body in stead of headers.  In a standalone test I'm using the following python code:

```
import preppy

premsg = preppy.getModule('email.prep')
print "========================================="
print premsg.get("sender@example.com", "recipient@example,com", "Message Subject", "https://followthislink.com/qwertyuiopp")
print "========================================="
```

And this template stored in email.prep

```
{{def(prepToAddr, prepFromAddr, prepSubject, prepLink)}}
To: {{prepToAddr}}
From: "{{prepFromAddr}}
Subject: {{prepSubject}}

Click this link to confirm your email address: {{prepLink}}
```

Which when run looks like this:

```
(email)tahaan@Komputer:~/Projects/email$ python prep1.py 
=========================================

To: sender@example.com
From: "recipient@example,com
Subject: Message Subject

Click this link to confirm your email address: https://followthislink.com/qwertyuiopp
=========================================
(email)tahaan@Komputer:~/Projects/email$
```

Should I just remove the leading blank line and live with it, or is there something I should be doing different to get the output right?

Answer (score 0):

To get this right you need to change the template to eliminate the eol at the end of the {{def()}} ie

```
{{def(prepToAddr, prepFromAddr, prepSubject, prepLink)}}To: {{prepToAddr}}
From: "{{prepFromAddr}}
Subject: {{prepSubject}}

Click this link to confirm your email address: {{prepLink}}
```

to eliminate the eol at the end you need an editor that doesn't put an eol in see eg [Vim no end of line on last line or eof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133501/vim-no-end-of-line-on-last-line-or-eof)