# Reading lines of text file in C++ fails due to hidden/control characters

Tags: c++, vim, text, ifstream

I have two text files, which appear to be identical in a text editor, but my C++ code for reading the files produces different line-counts for each file.  I can't figure out where the files are different, or how to accommodate such difference in my C++ code.

Let me explain...

I have two text files, d1.txt and d2.txt.  Each contains 100 numbers, 1 per line.  When I open either of the files in vim and enter `:set list!`, there are only 100 lines, each containing a number and the end-of-line character ($) after the last number on each line.  In other words, when looking at them in vim, they *look* identical, with the exception of different precision in the numbers.  There is different precision because one file came from MATLAB and the other from Gnumeric.

A quick diff of the files renders the following output (I use braced elipses "[...]" to omit portions in the interest of space):

```
1,28c1,28
< 0.01218465532007
       [...]
< 0.01327976337895
---
> 0.0121846553200678
       [...]
> 0.0132797633789485
30,100c30,100
< 0.01329705254301
       [...]
< 0.00017832496354
---
> 0.0132970525430057
       [...]
> 0.000178324963543758
\ No newline at end of file
```

Despite the message about the absence of a newline at the end of the second file (d2.txt), I can't *see* any difference when examining the last lines of the files in vim, as I mentioned above.

I have created a C++ function `readVectorFromFile(std::vector<double>&,const string)` that returns the number of lines read from the respective text file.  When I read the text files using the code:

```
std::cout << "d1.txt has " << readVectorFromFile(v1,"./d1.txt") << " lines.\n";
std::cout << "d2.txt has " << readVectorFromFile(v1,"./d1.txt") << " lines.\n";
```

I get the output:

```
d1.txt has 99 lines.
d2.txt has 100 lines.
```

The function is defined in the following way:

```
int readVectorFromFile(vector<double>& vec, const string& fullFilePathName) {

    int value, numLines;
    char line[10000];
    ifstream inFile;

    /* attempt to open file */
    inFile.open(fullFilePathName.c_str());
    if (inFile.fail()) {
        LOG(FATAL) << "Unable to open file \"" << fullFilePathName.c_str() << "\" for reading.";
    } else {
        cout << "Importing vector from file " << fullFilePathName.c_str() << "\n";
    }

    /* records the number of lines in the input file */
    numLines = static_cast<int>( count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile),
                                       istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n') );

    /* start file over from beginning */
    inFile.clear();
    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    vec.clear(); // clear current vec contents
    vec.reserve(numLines);

    /* read value from each line of file into vector */
    for(int i=0; i<numLines; ++i) {
        inFile.getline(line, 10000);
        vec.push_back( strtod(line,NULL) );
    }

    inFile.close(); // close filestream

    return numLines; // return the number of lines (values) read

}
```

Why can I not see the difference between these files when I view them in vim?  Is there anything fundamentally wrong with the above function that is causing this problem?

Comment: Add a newline to d1.txt. Vim renders a newline even if the file doesn't end in one. And your line count only counts newlines. So its not surprising that the line counts are off by one.

Comment: The above function will *not* be kind if your file has any double line breaks or blank lines. I *think* I understand what you're trying to do, and I think this could be simplified significantly.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, that function is just for my own personal use, and it depends on the assumptions of no double line breaks or blank lines.

Comment: @FDinoff is there any way to force vim to display all ASCII characters including new lines?  Seems like there should be, since vim is so powerful and customizable.

Comment: Actually it seems vim adds a new line to the end of the file it was missing one before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/vim-disable-automatic-newline-at-end-of-file) (And the newline will be there if you resave the file). And `:set list` is probably the closest you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, there is just no newline at the end of one of the two files. You can have a look at the files using, e.g., `od -c file | less` to see the exact content of the file, including their character codes.

That said, your approach to reading lines can probably be improved: Just read a line, check if it could be read, and process it. This way, there is no need to count the number of line endings up front:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(inFile, line); ) {
    vec.push_back(strtod(line.c_str()));
}
```

Personally, I would probably just read the numbers in the first place, e.g.:

```
for (double value; inFile >> value; ) {
    vec.push_back(value);
}
```

Well, that's not really the way to read a sequence of `double`s into a vector but this is:

```
std::vector<double> vec((std::istream_iterator<double>(inFile)),
                        std::istream_iterator<double>());
```

(instead of the extra parenthesis, you could use uniform initialization notation in C++11).

Comment: +1 If one-per-line is truly a requirement and there are more than that per line, its a little more involved (obviously) but not by much. Nice answer.

Comment: In your 3rd solution using istream_iterator, how could it be modified to read into the std::vector<double> that is passed by reference into the function? (Instead of declaring a new such object inside the function) I'm just curious.

Comment: @synaptik: Have a look at the `std::vector<T>` interface! You could, e.g., `v.swap(std::vector<std::string>(begin, end));` or `v.assign(begin, end)` (where `begin` and `end` are just the corresponding `std::istream_iterator<std::string>` objects).

Comment: That's very cool. Yes, I need to RTFM more. Never really tried to get into the more powerful aspects of the STL, but after this SO post, I think I will.