# Sqoop Import --password-file function not working properly in sqoop 1.4.4

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I am using hadoop-1.2.1 and sqoop version is 1.4.4.

I am trying to run the following query.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/database_name --table clients --target-dir /data/clients --username root --password-file /sqoop.password -m 1
```

`sqoop.password` is a file which is kept on HDFS in path `/sqoop.password` with permission 400.

It is giving me an error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'IP' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone provide solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"\n" is being written in file when you vi the file and write the password.
Better use the below approach to avoid problems

*`echo -n "Your_sqoop_password" > sqoop.password`*

Comment: Exactly. the password should be naked, no newline.

Comment: Or use vim as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/vim-disable-automatic-newline-at-end-of-file#16114535, since part of the point of using a password file is to avoid the password appearing wherever command line usages appear in logs or `ps`.

Comment: Perfect, this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if you are still having this issue. The password file can be in any folder. Try the following syntax and it should work:

```
--password-file file:///user/root/database.password
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same problem and got solved with this answer.

Comment: Thanks, and it worked for me as well. I would add that if you want it to look in hdfs, for me I had to use the following: `--password-file hdfs:///user/root/database.password`

Comment: I was getting an error that the provided password file did not exist. But adding file:/// as per this answer helped me solve that error

Answer (score 3):

As per the sqoop documentation

> You should save the password in a file on the **users home directory
>   with 400 permissions** and specify the path to that file using the
>   `--password-file argument`, and is the preferred method of entering credentials. Sqoop will then read the password from the file and pass
>   it to the MapReduce cluster using secure means with out exposing the
>   password in the job configuration. The file containing the password
>   can either be on the Local FS or HDFS.

If I am running my sqoop job with root user then my password file will be in `/user/root/` in **HDFS**

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://database.example.com/employees \
    --username venkatesh --password-file /user/root/database.password
```

For more details you can check [this](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_connecting_to_a_database_server)

Comment: Hi Prasad,
Didn't work on my end. It is giving the same error.

Comment: I had to place the password file into HDFS to get it to work. sigh.

Comment: yes as per the documentation that I have added above `The file containing the password can either be on the Local FS or HDFS.` and im my case I have placed the password file in `HDFS`

Answer (score 3):

While creating password, use `echo -n` option. (`-n` option removes all trailing spaces).
Suppose you have a password "myPassword" and you want to save it to a file `sqoop.password`, then follow below steps:

1. *Create password* using command

   ```
   echo -n "myPassword" > sqoop.password
   ```
2. *Upload the file to HDFS* as the file needs to be present in HDFS

   ```
   hadoop fs -put sqoop.password /user/keepMyFilesHere
   ```
3. *Write the scoop import command*

   ```
   sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/kpdatabase --username root --password-file /user/karanpreet.singh/sqoop.password
   ```

This will definitely work!

Comment: The subtlety that the password file must be in hadoop is missing from other answers, so this answer is more complete!

Comment: Using echo is not advised for shared environments since it makes the password visible to other users.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is any garbage character in your password file. I was getting the same issue and finally found that the file contained a \n character at the end  and sqoop considered that also as a part of the password string. Try creating a password file as mentioned below and than use the password file : 
    echo -n "root_password" > password.txt
Place your password in place of root_password.

Comment: On linux, ls -l, or wc will disclose the file size, and od -c or od -c (do you prefer character or hex output?) will show you the contents.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that the user running the `sqoop` command is the owner of the file `/sqoop.password` (which has the 400 permissions set). This will ensure that the password file is readable.
2. Make sure that the `sqoop.password` file does not have any extra non-printing characters at the end (for example, a newline character). One easy way to check this is to look at the size of the file. If the password is say *'sqoop'*, the size of the file should be 5. If it is larger, delete the `sqoop.password` file from HDFS, regenerate it locally and put it back on HDFS.


   The command that should report the above information pieces is:
   `hadoop fs -ls /sqoop.password`

Answer (score 0):

please follow below link for all your sqoop password related doubts.

[www.ericlin.me](https://www.ericlin.me/2015/06/securely-managing-passwords-in-sqoop/)