# How to store password in password file sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I want to store the password into a file & later use the same in sqoop command.

According to sqoop documentation `--password-file` option allow us for storing password. so i am storing it in pwd file with password abc text only. & hits the below command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db --username bhavesh --password-file /pwd --table t1 --target-dir '/erp/test'
```

assuming pwd file is stored over HDFS

as a result i am getting following error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'bhavesh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

When I perform the same operation using -p option it works fine for me.

Comment: For a normal sqoop import, have you tried this yet? 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36818269/1250410

Answer (score 1):

For a saved sqoop job, I was getting the same error. 
I stored the password in the metastore and that worked for me.

Making changes to the following configuration property in the file sqoop-site.xml which is usually stored here - /etc/sqoop/conf/sqoop-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.record.password</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>If true, allow saved passwords in the metastore.
    </description>
</property>
```

After making these changes, create the sqoop job and running the following command you would be able to see the password stored.

> sqoop job --show [job_name]

Answer (score 0):

You can store credential on HDFS.

Create credential using this command:

```
hadoop credential create mysql.password -provider jceks://hdfs/user/<your_hadoop_username>/mysqlpwd.jceks
```

When executed on the client machine it will ask to provide a password, then please enter the MySQL password that you were provided with -P option for sqoop command.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db --username bhavesh --password-alias mysql.password --table t1 --target-dir /erp/test
```

And run this modified command in that I have replaced

> --password-file

with

> --password-alias

File in hdfs contain a password in an encrypted format that cannot be recovered.