# Java file adds \r\n at the end of file - how to eliminate it?

Tags: java, file

I am creating a file for a rigid system that doesn't like \r\n at the end of the file. But while creating the file, java adds it automatically.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class FileTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileText = "a\r\nb";
        String filePath = "/log/engines/Testfile.txt";


        FileOutputStream out = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream( filePath);
            byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            char[] charArr = fileText.toCharArray();
            for( int i=0; i<charArr.length; i++) {
                byteOut.write( charArr[i]);
//              out.write( charArr[i]);
            }
            byteOut.writeTo( out);
            System.out.println( "Last Char in File =" +charArr[charArr.length-1] +"=" +(int)charArr[charArr.length-1]);
        } finally {
            if (byteOut != null) {
                byteOut.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

The binary of this file is as below -

```
610d 0a62 0d0a == (a\r \nb \r\n)

0d = "\r"
0a = "\n"
```

I am fine with the first "\r\n" which I am adding, but not the last one that gets added by itself. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have to use a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: are you opening the file in another editor after the fact?  (neither FileOutputStream nor ByteArrayOutputStream will add the problem characters)

Comment: Running the code you supplied (only change: value of filePath) on a Windows machine with Java 1.7.0_60 outputs `Last Char in File =b=98`. When I open the Testfile.txt in a text editor, it does not show any newline (\r\n) after the "b".

Comment: Running your code on a Mac `hexdump Testfile.txt` outputs `61 0d 0a 62`

Comment: When I run this program in Windows and I see correct values in the hex viewer (https://hexed.it/?hl=en), but when I view the file using vi, and Escape followed by :%!xxd, it displays \r\n codes at end.

Comment: @Daniel I get the following output if I use hexdump. Sorry, I don't understand this output.

#hexdump Testfile.txt
0000000 0d61 620a
0000004

Comment: so the answer is that vi is modifying your doc. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/vim-disable-automatic-newline-at-end-of-file)

Comment: Ah, you're on a different system so the big-endianness appears to be different.  tryin hexdump -C instead, it should be more clear.