# Why is there an extra new line character when I create a string using init(contentsOfFile:)?

Tags: swift, string, newline

I tried to read the contents of a file in my bundle and put it into a string variable. I used the `init(contentsOfFile:)` initializer. However, there always seems to be an extra `\n` character at the end of the string.

Here is an MCVE:

```
let string = try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "txt")!)
print(string.debugDescription)
```

`test.txt` is like this:

```
Hello
World
Bye
World
```

Note that I did not insert a new line at the end. This can be proven by looking at the line count:

[image]

The above code produces this output:

```
"Hello\nWorld\nBye\nWorld\n"
```

Note the last character being a `\n`.

This causes a lot of trouble for me. I am splitting the string using `\n` as the delimiter and then parsing each line. The `\n` at the end causes an empty string to be in the split string. I don't want that.

I think I can just call `dropLast` to remove the last character, but I'm not sure whether a new line character will *always* appear at the end when I do this, since I can't find any documentation. If by chance an extra new line character is not added to the end, then my `dropLast` call will incorrectly remove a "useful" character.

Why is a new line added? Does this always happen?

Comment: Is the last `\n` character coming from `print` itself? Try adding a new line character at the end, and see if printing produces two `\n` at the end. Also try `let hasEol = string.last!=="\n"` and see what you get back.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I added a new line at the end of the file, but the print output is still `"Hello\nWorld\nBye\nWorld\n"`. This seems like that the new line will only be added if there isn't a new line in the file... `string.last!=="\n"` is true.

Comment: There must be an extra `\n` at the end. Look at the hex representation with right-click > Open As > Hex. I guess that's a *bad* behavior of Xcode while saving the file in the editor. Open the file with an external editor and remove the linefeed character.

Comment: @vadian I see a `0A` at the end. Is that a new line? If it is, why is that added?

Comment: Yes `0A` is new line. As mentioned above I assume that the character is added implicitly while saving the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a behaviour of Xcode.
To test this you can view the file with the line breaks by right clicking on the file as selecting

Open As -> Hex

If this behaviour is undesired you can use `vim` within the Terminal and disable the addition:

[VIM Disable Automatic Newline At End Of File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050640/vim-disable-automatic-newline-at-end-of-file)

Comment: vim will add a newline character unless you set the file type as binary.

Comment: Info on vim and suppressing last newline https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050640/1630618

Comment: Thanks man, I use  `vi` in tmux and forgot that that I've got it set up to disable this. 