# Python adds a new line at the end of opened file

Tags: python, file, newline

While writing some tests, i got stuck on some weird behavior. I finally narrow the problem to file opening. For instance, this one, `my.dat`:

```
one line
two lines and no final line break
```

I then ran that python code:

```
with open('my.dat') as fd:
    assert fd.read()[-1] == '\n'
```

With both python 3 and 2, this code does not raise any AssertError.

My question is: why forcing the presence of line jump at the end of files ?

Comment: You should probably open the file with `mode='r'` if you are not writing to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works here. Are you 100% sure that there is not actually a newline at the end of your file? Because many text editors (atom, notepad++) automatically add newlines at the end of a file.

```
>>> open('a.txt', 'w').write('blabla')
6
>>> open('a.txt', 'r').read()
'blabla'
>>> assert open('a.txt', 'r').read()[-1] == '\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

Comment: Scheiße… My vim seems to be contaminated by this behavior. The problem is all about vim now. That's a plot twist. Thanks !   (*[fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114535/3077939)*)

Comment: That is the posix-standard way of writing a file.  Vim actually warns you when it opens a file with no newline (it says NOEOL at the bottom), but when it writes the file out, it will add the missing newline.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline

Comment: As usual, i found an odd behavior, be pissed about it for ten minutes, then SO's community changes my mind.