# Unable to remove a line feed with VIM

Tags: linux, vim, linefeed, nano

When I edit a file in vim or nano on multiple terminal emulators it is adding a line feed to my files.

xxd of file before edit:

```
00001880: 5645 5574 4c53 3074 4c51 6f3d            VEUtLS0tLQo=
```

xxd of file after an edit, save but no changes (made by me) to the file:

```
00001880: 5645 5574 4c53 3074 4c51 6f3d 0a         VEUtLS0tLQo=.
```

I thought you could use `:set list` in vim and then remove the line feed.  That does not seem to be the case.  Vim is displaying a $ at the end of each line, however I am unable to see the LF and remove it.  I have also tried `:set binary`, `:set ++ffs=unix`, `sed -i 's/\r$//' file` and other options.  What am I missing here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050640/1030675

Answer (score 1):

I think that the option that you need is this

```
:set nofixendofline
```

you can include the option in the `.vimrc` file

```
" .vimrc file

autocmd Filetype <your-filetype> set nofixendofline
```

you can find more information here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114535/4681320

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the way textfiles are defined in Unix. More specifically, a POSIX "text file" must end in a newline (or be an empty file).

To quote the POSIX [definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206):

> ###### 3.403 Text File
>
> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. [...]

> ###### 3.206 Line
>
> A sequence of zero or more non-  characters plus a terminating  character.

That is, whenever Vim saves the file, it appends a newline.

See also: [Why should text files end with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/729692/2057969)

As a commenter points out, solutions are discussed here: [How to stop vim from adding a newline at end of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050640/2057969)